# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server

Tags: javascript, websocket, firefox-addon, livereload

I have been looking into this for 2 or 3 days but could not find a solution.

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:35729/livereload

See the error screenshot:

[image]

See the following `chromerealod.ts` code:

```
const LIVERELOAD_HOST = 'localhost:';
const LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
const connection = new WebSocket(`ws://${LIVERELOAD_HOST}${LIVERELOAD_PORT}/livereload`);

connection.onerror = (error) => {
  console.log('reload connection got error:', error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
};

connection.onopen = () => {
  console.log('Livereload socket connected.'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
};
connection.onmessage = (e) => {
  if (e.data) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data && data.command === 'reload') {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
        console.log("tabs:" + tabs);
        if ( tabs.length > 0 ) {
          console.log('Reloading tab', tabs[0].id, tabs[0].url);
          chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
        }
        browser.runtime.reload();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Well, let's start with the obvious - are you even running a WebSocket server on `localhost:35729` to begin with?

Comment: @Remy lebeau `It is running fine on the chrome and get connected to websocket link of livereload`.

Comment: @AbdulQadir , the same: works in Chrome but not in Firefox. And I've just noticed that I use VPN in Firefox. Disabling it has helped.